# Timer is not cancelling

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, timertask

None of the other instances of this question are solving my problem. I have a Fragment that appears at the end of a transaction sequence. It is meant to close the app when a `Timer` contained within it completes:

```
var terminalTimer: Timer? = null

class TerminalFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_terminal, container, false)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()


    initUi()
    startCountDown()

}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()

    AppLog.i(TAG, "onStop()")

    stopCountDown()

}

private fun startCountDown() {

    if (terminalTimer == null) {
        terminalTimer = Timer()

        terminalTimer!!.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {

                AppLog.i(TAG, "Terminal countdown finished")

            {

                    activity?.finish()


            }

        }, 5000)
    }

}

private fun stopCountDown() {

    AppLog.i(TAG, "stopCountDown()")

    terminalTimer?.cancel()
    terminalTimer?.purge()
    terminalTimer = null

}

private fun returnToStart() {

    AppLog.i(TAG, "returnToStart()")

    (context as MainActivity).restartFlow() // calls popBackStackImmediate() for every fragment in the backstack, returning user to the beginning of their flow
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(terminalType: String, amountLoaded: Double) =
        TerminalFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {

            }
        }
}
```

}

`stopCountDown()` is being called whenever the fragment is navigated away from, but it somehow survives sometimes and closes the app from another Fragment. Using logs, I've also discovered that there appears to be 2 instances of this timer sometimes. How do I insure that this countdown is never active outside of this fragment and is cancelled/ destroyed in the Fragment's onStop()?

Comment: The `Timer`'s _cancel_ method does not interfere with any actively running tasks but the scheduled ones. So if the task is currently running, calling `cancel` will not affect it.

Comment: Is a task considered running during the delay period? Because that's typically when I'm calling .cancel()

Comment: How is it that you can call `finish()` from a non-UI thread without crashing? Never tried it, myself, but it's surprising. Your original `CountDownTimer` approach made a lot more sense, IMHO.